# Stacked bar chart in Qlik Sense: one bar for one field

Tags: bar-chart, stacked-chart, qliksense, stackedbarseries

I have this table:

```
Survey1:
LOAD * inline [
Respondent, AnswerToQuestion1, AnswerToQuestion2
resp1, 1, 1
resp2, 1, 2
resp3, 2, 1
resp4, 2, 1
resp5, 2, 3
resp6, 2, 1
resp7, 2, 1
resp8, 3, 2
resp9, 3, 2
];
```

I want to get a 100% stacked bar chart from this data. But it is difficult both, in Excel and in Qlick Sense... These programs do not accept that I would want to summarise one field/column into one bar.

My desired result should look similar to this:
[image: stacked bar graph 100%]

Is there a way to do so in Qlik Sense?

Comment: **Key takeaway.** Not all programs can take microdata and output graphs. Sometimes you will need to do intermediate aggregations to make a table suitable to the algorithm which draws the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to alter the way the data is modelled using [unpivot](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/LoadData/unpivot-crosstable.htm)/[crosstable](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm) - which would create a table more like:

```
Respondent, Question, Answer
resp1, Question1, 1
resp1, Question2, 1
resp2, Question1, 1
resp2, Question2, 2
```

You could then make a stacked bar chart with 2 dimensions - Question & Answer with `count(Answer)/count(TOTAL<Respondent>Answer)` as your measure to give you a percentage. Note: I haven't tested that code - I'd start with a table with those 2 dimensions and `count(Answer)` as a measure - then check that `count(TOTAL<Respondent>Answer)` gives the total number of answers you'd expect.

In the script editor, assuming your table is called "Answers" this could be done with something like:

```
Answers_new:
crosstable(Question,Answer,1)
Load * resident Answers;
drop table Answers;
rename table Answers_new to Answers;
```